# How to get cookies to save for all pages in cURL PHP?

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I am trying to use cURL to access a webpage, and I need to save the associated cookies. The code is working for only some pages. Is it because cookies are written in javascript on the pages that cookies do not save? Here is my code:

```
function httpGet($url)
{
$ch = curl_init();  

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS,2);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookie.txt');


$output=curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
return $output;
}

echo httpGet("http://www.aol.com/"); //Saves cookies to cookie.txt
echo httpGet("http://www.supremenewyork.com/"); //Does not save cookies
```

How can I make it so the cookies are saved on this page? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
```

try to add referer when curl to that url

Comment: Added those and still no cookies. Hmm